# A web comic where a woman in a hoodie asks what universe she is in?

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, webcomics

Some years back I read a beautifully illustrated fantasy web comic, rather surreal.

All I remember is a woman in a hoodie stumbling into some alternate world. She zipped up her hoodie to obscure her face and asked some creature something like "Excuse me, but which universe is this?" Can anyone tell me what comic this is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Was it [this episode](http://dresdencodak.com/2006/07/24/girl-vs-bear/) of Dresden Codak?

Comment: That's it, thank you very much!